# running a job in unix

Tags: bash, unix

I have the following small script - myjob.qsub:

```
#!/bin/sh -login
#PBS -l walltime=00:15:00
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
#PBS -l mem=2gb 
#PBS -N myrun05168
/myexecutable >mylog.log
```

I did make it executable by:

```
chmod u+x myexecutable
```

When I try to run by changing directory to the folder of executible and then sumbit the job:

```
qsub myjob.qsub
```

gives me error of no  /myexecutable file or directory.

I tried to use "./":

```
     #!/bin/sh -login
     #PBS -l walltime=00:15:00
      #PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
      #PBS -l mem=2gb 
     #PBS -N myrun05168
    ./myexecutable >mylog.log
```

but doesnot help.

when I just tried to run my executable in command line as, it works:

```
./myexecutable
```

As I can not run this as this job need to be submitted as job in cluster computer.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to give the full path to the script, I assume the script isn't actually in your root directory, maybe it should be /home/username/myexecutable

Comment: My executable is in side this directory, /mnt/home/username/myruns/p_runs/Fw2010/seed1, when I tried to change the secript replacing with /mnt/home/username/myruns/p_runs/Fw2010/seed1 > mylog.log, it doesnot produce any output, the error log is blank !!

Comment: You need to use the full path to the log file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your script runs with -login, is that needed?

You should change your script to use the relative pathname, like

```
myruns/p_runs/Fw2010/seed1/myexecutable >mylog.log
```